# Apache 2.2.17 + wamp + windows 7 + gives 403 when configure virtual host

Tags: php, wamp, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/projects/RnD"
    ServerName dev.ei-rnd.loc
    <Directory "D:/projects/RnD">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache : 2.2.17**

I have written above code to configure virtualhost in newly installed wamp. It gives me 403 error when dev.ei-rnd.loc hit on browser.

**Please Note:**

Already tried below options

1. uncomment **Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/projects/RnD"
    ServerName dev.ei-rnd.loc
    <Directory "D:/projects/RnD">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```